# I'm getting an OutOfMemoryError while trying to fill a stack array with int values

Tags: java, stack

I've been working on the towers of hanoi recursion using stacks but im getting an OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in the hanoi function

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Hanoi {

    public static Stack<Integer>[] towersOfHanoi = new Stack[4];
    public static int moves;

    public static void hanoi(int n) {

        for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            towersOfHanoi[i] = new Stack<Integer>();
        }

        for(int i = n; n > 0; i--) {
            towersOfHanoi[1].push(i);
        }

        moveDisc(n, 1, 2, 3);
    }

    public static void moveDisc(int n, int peg1, int peg2, int peg3) {

        moveDisc(n-1, peg1, peg2, peg3);
        int i = towersOfHanoi[peg1].pop();
        towersOfHanoi[peg2].push(i);
        moves++;
        moveDisc(n-1, peg3, peg1, peg2);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        towersOfHanoi[1] = new Stack<Integer>();
        towersOfHanoi[2] = new Stack<Integer>();
        towersOfHanoi[3] = new Stack<Integer>();

        System.out.println("Enter number of discs: ");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        in.close();

        hanoi(n);

        System.out.println(moves);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the second for loop in the hanoi function

```
for(int i = n; n > 0; i--) {
        towersOfHanoi[1].push(i);
    }
```

should be

```
for(int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        towersOfHanoi[1].push(i);
    }
```

before you had it as 'n>0', but n will never change. You want it to be 'i>0'

I should also mention, you will probably get infinite recursion in the moveDisk method. You should make a base case. But, this will fix the OOM error you got in the hanoi function

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void moveDisc(int n, int peg1, int peg2, int peg3) {
    moveDisc(n-1, peg1, peg2, peg3);
    ...
```

Method `moveDisc` immediately reinvokes itself without any test to break the recursion.  Thus you are in an infinite recursion and quickly exhaust all stack space.

The algorithm for this problem is extremely well documented lots of places on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your code will run an infinite recursion.
i don't exactly remember the hanoi solving method, but from the looks of it you are trying to run a recursive algorithm based on 'n' but you never check for a base condition, like when n reaches 1 or 0;